# Chart js, plugins afterDatasetUpdate not changing text value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I can see `console.log('here');` and `console.log(args.meta._dataset.data[0]);` logs in console so function is triggering when datasets value change. But I can't see the text. What can be the reason?

Props:

```js
  const updateGaugeChartText = {
    id: 'currentChartValue',
    afterDatasetUpdate(chart: any, args: any, pluginOptions: any) {
      const { ctx } = chart;
      ctx.save();
      console.log('here');
      console.log(args.meta._dataset.data[0]);
      const xCoor = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0].x;
      const yCoor = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0].y;
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.font = '32px sans-serif';
      ctx.fillText(args._dataset, xCoor, yCoor);
    },
  };

  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
      },
    },
  };

  const data = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [exactValue, item.minMaxValue.max - exactValue],
        backgroundColor: [bgColor2, bgColor3],
        hoverOffset: 0,
        borderWidth: 0,
        cutout: '70%',
        circumference: 180,
        rotation: 270,
      },
    ],
  };
```

Component:

```js
<Doughnut plugins={[updateGaugeChartText]} ref={chart} options={options} data={data} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw something in the canvas, you can not hook the `afterDatasetUpdate` because this is invoked when the dataset are updated, not drawn.
You should use `afterDatasetDraw` hook.

```
  const updateGaugeChartText = {
    id: 'currentChartValue',
    afterDatasetDraw(chart, args, pluginOptions) {
      const { ctx } = chart;
      const meta = args.meta;
      const xCoor = meta.data[0].x;
      const yCoor = meta.data[0].y;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.font = '32px sans-serif';
      ctx.fillText(chart.data.datasets[0].data[0], xCoor, yCoor);
      ctx.restore();
    },
  };
```